# How to include header file from different workspace?

Tags: ros, c++, cmake, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I am new to ROS and its my first post, so I hope everything is understandable.

I am trying to include a header file in the package (B) from a different package (A) which is in a different workspace. I can include messages from the package.
I overlayed the workspace and added the the packge in the CMakeLsts.txt

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
A
)

catkin_package(
CATKIN_DEPENDS
A
)

install (DIRECTORY include/${A}/
DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")

add_library(library A/src/AClass.cpp)

add_executable(ClassIncludeAClass  src/ClassIncludeAClass.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ClassIncludeAClass   ${catkin_LIBRARIES} library )
```

ClassIncludeAClass .cpp

```
#include "A/AClass.h"
```

When I include the whole path to the file the Compiler has undefined references to functions of the class AClass.

I found the following question https://answers.ros.org/question/201977/include-header-file-from-another-package-indigo/ to include a header form the same Workspace but a different package.

Thanks in advance for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279929/how-to-include-header-file-from-different-workspace?/) by [Kiwi](https://answers.ros.org/users/33311/kiwi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2018-01-16**:
I think you are missing this:
`include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})` which will tell the compiler to look for include files also in the include folders of the packaged that you found in `find_package`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm assuming this is the `CMakeLists.txt` of package  `B`.

Thus, the `install(..` part makes no sense. Why would you want to install something from INSIDE package `B`? Do you have a layout like `B/include/A`? Also, what do you expect `${A}` do contain? This variable should not be set anywhere in here.

The same holds for the `add_library` call. Why do you, in package `B` want to build a package in `A`.

The answer you cite is correct, so please follow this.

- In pkg `A`:

  - compile the library
  - install the library and Header files of pkg `A` (actually, not even required)
  - Export the include path and the library with the `catkin_package` call (check out the template when you create a new package)
- In pkg `B`:

  - set up the `build_depend` to pkg `A`
  - `find_package` package `A`
  - add `include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})`
  - include the Header in your package `B` code
  - link against the `${catkin_LIBRARIES}`

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0